# Is there some way that PHP can control CSS

Tags: php, css

1) database

2) php

3) css

4) html form

The user enters some properties for example background: red in the html form and it saves in the db, then php loades from the db the color option in background css... and then how can I put php variable in the css properties...

also some hostings does not allow to add handlers in .htaccess, is there other options?

Comment: You can actually, several different ways. See answers below.

Comment: Too much complicated answer. Just make the different classes in the css. Then call those classes from database in the html. Job done!

Comment: Key part here being "User enters properties" Not hardwired css classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can serve a css file with php by setting the content-type.

```
<?php header('content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

You would output the css from the php file.

You could store values in a mySQL or other table with a form, and later retrieve them with the mySQLi or other library.

This is an example of the php script:

```
<?
    header('content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8');

    $bgColor = "#FFF"; // Get it from database, I'm setting manually for this example
?>

body{
      background-color:<?php echo "$bgColor" ?>;
}
```

Alternatively, you could output inline css on the page. Either directly in to a  tag, or inline on elements.

If really needed a native css file for some reason (I can't think of one), you could technically overwrite a specific css file using php's fwrite() function, though I wouldn't recommend doing it this way.

```
 <?php

      $filename = "phpstyle.css";

      $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

      $bgcolor = "#FFF";

      $css  = "body{";
      $css .= "background-color:".$bgcolor.";"; 
      $css .= "}";           

      fwrite($fp, $css);

      fclose($fp);

 ?>
```

Comment: No worries. I just elaborated on the answer to include sample code for writing a css file to disk using php.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can serve a css through php script.

One method is to output style elements through php.

```
<?php
    #css on php file
    $color = '#FFFFFF';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Css through php</title>
    <style>
        .test{
            text-color: <?php echo $color;  ?> 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="test">Your body </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Another method is to generate css dynamically in a php file and linking it on an html page.

```
<?php
    #css on php file [test_css.php]
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    $color = '#FFFFFF';
?>
.test{
            text-color: <?php echo $color;  ?> 
}
```

---

```
<html>
<!-- test.html -->
<head>
    <title>Css through php</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_css.php">
</head>
<body>
<p class="test">Your body </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but unfortunately not all hostings allow to handle php in css files

Comment: @RustamKichinsky You're thinking of it the wrong way around. You don't put PHP in a CSS document but rather generate a CSS document with PHP.

Comment: @MartyWallace it would be more work for php than...better sick to straight stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Khaleel's answer, you can put CSS in the HTML document itself, in a

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

section. You can use PHP variables to fill this in.

Or you can use inline styles in the HTML

```
<span style="...">...</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
<?php if (myCondition) { ?>
<style>.myClass {
background: <?php echo $myColor; ?> !important;
} </style>
<?php } ?>
```

The myCondition triggers the insertion of in body styling. The !important tag overwrites all other existing value of that property.

Simple to understand and easy to use. Works every time.

Answer (score -1):

ether create a css file using php dynamically, such as:

```
<link href="../styles/styles.php" type="text/css" />
```

or use php to write the css inline on your html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
   background-color: <?php echo $redcolor; ?>;
}
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

however,  you cannot create a standard css file with php.

Comment: you can <?
    header('content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8');

    $bgColor = "#FFF"; // Get it from database, I'm setting manually for this example
?>

body{
      background-color:<?php echo "$bgColor" ?>;
}

Comment: yes, you can write css using your php file, exactly like you just said. However, because php is server side code, and css is client side. To my knowledge you cant create a "styles.css" and use php to write styles inline said .css file. a "styles.css". Not without writing a new file anyway. What you described is the use case of the first code snippet.

Comment: i think you can... may be i am wrong

i.e <link .... href="style.css.php" ...> will do if you have the proper header ...

Comment: right, the key is ".php" in the link tag and the content header on said php file. I've used that technique before, but its been quite a while.

Comment: i dont know abt css but for js specially ajax stuff, when we need to get php variables into the js files and for security reasons when we want to hide the js code this technique is usefull, but not sure abt css i think its part of the design rather than the programming ...